# Gaussian elimination without matrix storage

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have a problem in performing Gaussian elimination. The matrix A is quite large and can't be stored with my memory constraints, however, the elements of A can be described as a function of i and j, i.e., A(i,j) = f(i,j).

In addition, I don't need to calculate all the elements of the resulting upper triangular matrix.

The question now,
how to update the algorithm of Gaussian elimination to use f(i,j) to calculate a specific element of the resulting matrix in stead of calculate all the elements?

update:
this is my A matrix:

```
                a_{11} & a_{12}  & a_{13}  & a_{14}  & .. & a_{1L} 
                q_1    & a_{22}  & a_{23}  & a_{23}  & .. & a_{2L} 
                q_2    & q_1     & a_{33}  & a_{34}  & .. & a_{3L} 
                q_3    & q_2     & q_1     & a_{44}  & .. & a_{3L} 
                q_4    & q_3     & q_2     & q_1     & .. & a_{3L} 
                 :     &  :      & :       & :       & :  & : 
                 :     &  :      & :       & :       & :  & : 
                q_L    & q_{L-1} & q_{L-2} & q_{L-3} & .. & a_{LL}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't need to calculate all the elements of the resulting upper triangular matrix." The algorithm I know by this name requires just that.

Comment: @laune "a matrix so big you can't store it? This is 2014!" One could conceivably ask for an algorithm that runs on an infinite matrix. The output then would be a function returning the result at a specified entry. Certainly there are infinite matrices that you can [compute the spectrum](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114048/how-to-diagonalize-infinite-symmetric-banded-matrices) for.

Comment: @laune: as Hooked said, the matrix is infinite but I have a function that I can use to get a certain element. And thank you for reminding me to adjust my calender!

Comment: @Hamid what is the function you are using evaluate the element A(i,j). Knowing period of function would also help reduce the memory and calculations

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to calculate the entry `(m,n)`. `m` the row, `n` the column.

First:
If `m > n` the entry will be zero, because it is under the diagonal.
If `m = n` the entry will be one (the entry is on the diagonal)

So let `m < n`.

I think you can compute this entry by only storing `m^2+m` entrys:

1. Save the first `m` entrys and the `n`th entry of the first row with the first entry is not zero. call this entrys `M_11,M_12,...,M_1m,M_1n`.
2. divide every entry `M_i` by `M_1`
3. save the first `m` entrys and the `n`th entry of the first row `y` with `y_2 - y_1 * M_12` is not zero.
4. save this row as `M_21,M_22,...M_2m,M_2n`
5. for `i = 2 ... m` do `M_2i = M_2i - M_1i * M_21`
6. do the same with the next rows: search a row that have a non zero entry on the diagonal (after subtracting the saved rows)

At the end (after `m` rows) entry `M_mn` contains your result.

*Notice*: If you have to switch two rows you have to save the new order of the rows.

About space and time:
You can use space to buy some time and the other way around. If you don't want to save the `m^2` entrys, it may be possible to store only `2m` entrys, but this will cost you a lot of time, up to exponential time in `m`.

If you know more about `f(i,j)`, there could be a way to speed the algorithm up or reduce the required space.

Comment: Thank your for the response, however, we still have the same problem of saving huge amount of data.
- what do you mean by y in step 3?
- how do you suggest to update the algorithm to store only 2m entries?

Comment: I thought about somethink like a recursive function. basicly you have to calculate everything always new, so you only store a constant many numbers per call. the problem is, that the time-complexity will be huge. If `m` is to big to store m^2 values, this function will never give you a result. have you any more information about `f(i,j)`?

Comment: `y` is just the name of the row that satisfy the constrain. its not easy to discribe what entrys i mean if the have no name^^